# JavaFX Clipboard distorts images. DPI to blame?

Tags: java, scala, javafx

When trying to show an image stored in the system clipboard, I ran into this problem: the resulting picture is always bigger than the original and a bit blurry.

Here's what I used (in Scala):

No, my code is exactly the same, it's just in Scala (I also tried running the Java version, the same result)

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.stage.Stage

object Test extends App{
  Application.launch(classOf[HelloWorld], args: _*)
}

class HelloWorld extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!")
    val root = new StackPane        
    val image = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getImage()
    val imageView = new ImageView(image)
    root.getChildren.add(imageView)
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250))
    primaryStage.show
  }
}
```

Original picture and what ImageView makes of it:
[http://imgur.com/AFJudkL](https://imgur.com/AFJudkL)

I've also tried saving the image to a file and it's still distorted, so the problem is not in ImageView.

Even had a wild idea to call SetProcessDPIAware from WinAPI, had absolutely no effect.

Is there any way to show the image without distortions?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I've provided the full version of the code (It's exactly the same as the Java version below. I'm running it on Windows 10, jdk1.8.0_131, DPI is set to 175%.

I'm more and more certain that the problem I'm having is because of DPI - the image ImageView is showing is exactly 1.75 times larger that the original. Now I can force it to be of the right size with the following trick:

```
imageView.setFitHeight(image.getHeight/1.75)
imageView.setFitWidth(image.getWidth/1.75)
```

But it's still blurry. Also I found a great blog post that deals with that problem (different aspect of it, though - snapshot taking). However, I have no idea how to apply this solution to my conundrum.

http://news.kynosarges.org/2017/02/01/javafx-snapshot-scaling/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the preserveRatio property of the image view.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#preserveRatioProperty

Update:

I converted your code fragment into an executable example and when I run this on my Mac (Retina) I don't see any distortion at all. So, how is your code (which you didn't provide) different from mine and what are the relevant characteristics of your Windows box?

```
public class ClipboardBug extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
          primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
          StackPane root = new StackPane();
          Image image = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getImage();
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
          imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
          root.getChildren().add(imageView);
          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
          primaryStage.sizeToScene();
          primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: No, tried it, has no effect whatsoever. Besides, as I said, even without showing the image in ImageView, it's already distorted. The problem definitely lies in the way Clipboard handles it.